# How to remove an unnecessary space between elements?

Tags: html

Below, the `<h3>` tag creates a space, and the code gets formatted weirdly. How do you get rid of the space between the 80 and the + sign? The counter-up module that I used is from this link: https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html

```
    <section id = "cta" class = "wrapper style3">
        <div class = "row uniform">
            <div class = "4u 6u$(2) 12u$(3)">
                <h2><u>Students</u></h2>
            </div>
            <div class = "4u 6u(2) 12u$(3)">
                <h3 class = "counter">80</h3><h3>+</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
                $('.counter').counterUp({
                    delay: 30,
                    time: 1500
                });
            });
        </script>
    </section>
```

Comment: You're gonna have to post at least the CSS you have for an H3. But most likely you'll need to adjust some margin and/or padding.

Answer (score 1):

Headings are block-level elements meaning two adjacent headings will be rendered on two separate lines (as long as you haven't tinkered with their presentation via CSS).

You can use CSS to append the "+" to the H3 content instead of using another adjacent H3 element:

```css
h3.counter:after {
  content: "+";
  display: "inline";
}
```

```html
<h2>Without CSS:</h2>
<h3>80</h3><h3>+</h3>
<h2>With CSS:</h2>
<h3 class="counter">80</h3>
```

Comment: I might caution that the `content` tag means the text is no longer selectable